# Java regex help

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression for Java's String.matches(regex) method to match a file extension. I tried .*.ext but this doesn't match files ending in .ext just ext
I then tried `.*\.ext` and this worked in a regular expression tester but in Eclipse I am getting an invalid escape sequence error.
Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In eclipse (java), the regex String need to be "escaped":

```
".*\\.ext"
```

Comment: And yet your answer was helpful (which is the criteria) and more succinct for those of us who tire easily, so +1 right back at ya :-)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a test program that shows you the regex to use:

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String re = "^.*\\.ext$";
        String [] strings = new String[] {
            "file.ext", ".ext",
            "file.text", "file.ext2",
            "ext"
        };
        for (String str : strings) {
            System.out.println (str + " matches('" + re + "') is " +
                (str.matches (re) ? "true" : "false"));
        }
    }
}
```

and here's the output (slightly edited for "beauty"):

```
file.ext   matches('^.*\.ext$') is true
.ext       matches('^.*\.ext$') is true
file.text  matches('^.*\.ext$') is false
file.ext2  matches('^.*\.ext$') is false
ext        matches('^.*\.ext$') is false
```

But you don't really need that, a simple

```
str.endsWith (".ext")
```

will do just as well for this particular job.

If you need the comparison to be case insensitive (.EXT, .eXt, ...) for Windows, you can use:

```
str.toLowerCase().endsWith(".ext")
```

Comment: Much more detailed than my answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

For such a simple scenario, why don't you just use [String.endsWith](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String))?

Comment: I didn't even think of that.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Matches a dot followed by zero or more non-dots and end of string:

```
\.[^.]*$
```

Note that if that's in a Java string literal, you need to escape the backslash:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\.[^.]*$");
```